# Extend Struct definition golang

Tags: go

I want to extend a struct definition from that of the other

```
type A struct {
    name string
}

type B struct {
    A
}
```

So here A is a sub struct of B. But I do not want that. Instead I want the B's definition to be the same as A without any nesting

```
    var a A
    var b B
    fmt.Printf("%v, %v \t", a, b)

    a.name = "john"
    b.name = "rick"

    fmt.Printf("%v, %v \t", a, b)
```

So output of this is `{john} {{rick}}`. I want it to be `{john}{rick}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
type B A
```

However, if you do this, any methods you defined for `A` will not be available for `B`.